# Beginner problem dart/flutter: Extracting information from a list

Tags: flutter, dart

Thank you for reading this question.

I'm very new to dart/flutter and I'm trying to write some code so that I can create a list of the actDescriptions where they have more than 1 traits associated to them, showing the associated traits.

Thank you again.

```dart
 const ACTION_DATA = const [
    ActionOutput(
      id: 'a1',
      actDescription: 'Avoid caffeine 4 hours before going to bed for high quality sleep.',

      traits: [
        'T_CAFFEINE_INTAKE_BAND',
      ],

    ),
    ActionOutput(
      id: 'a2',
      actDescription: 'Avoid caffeine altogether if you struggle with falling asleep.',

      traits: [
        'T_CAFFEINE_INTAKE_BAND',
        'T_SLEEP_BAND',
      ],

    ),
    ActionOutput(
      id: 'a3',
      actDescription: 'Use caffeine to boost exercise performance.',

      traits: [
        'T_CAFFEINE_INTAKE_BAND',
      ],

    ),
    ActionOutput(
      id: 'a4',
      actDescription: 'If you have caffeine pre-workout, have it around 30-15 minutes before you train.',

      traits: [
        'T_CAFFEINE_INTAKE_BAND',
      ],

    ),
    ActionOutput(
      id: 'a5',
      actDescription: 'Don\'t use coffee as a \"pick me up\" during the day.',

      traits: [
        'T_CAFFEINE_INTAKE_BAND',
      ],

    ),
];
```

Comment: hi dan. please fix the formatting of your code (indentation) so we can understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ListView.builder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html) constructor to create a scrollable list of your `ActionOutput` items. The constructor expects an `itemBuilder`, which is just callback function that is expected to create and return a new item for the desired index in your list.

In the example below we use the `ListView.builder` and delegate the item widget creation to the `_buildActionItem` method.

```dart
Widget _buildTraitItem(trait) {
  // this can be any widget to display a trait
  return Text(trait);
}

Widget _buildActionItem(ActionOutput action) {
  // create a new action item
  // this can be any widget, here we use a simple container with a single column
  // and a row for the traits

  // build a list of trait items
  final traits = action.traits.map(_buildTraitItem).toList();

  return Container(
    height: 50,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text(action.actDescription),
        Row(
            // use the list of items in this row
            children: traits
        )
      ]
    )
  );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: ACTION_DATA.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      // create an item for the requested index based on the item data
      return _buildActionItem(ACTION_DATA[index]);
    },
  );
}
```

For more examples on how to create a list see the [`ListView` documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html).

Comment: Hey, Hannes. Thank you so much for helping me with this. What a great place!